# Given k sleeping threads how can I wake them up in a fifo order in c

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, thread-sleep

Given k sleeping threads how can I wake them up in a fifo order in c
I want to search for a term in a dir and I have a queue with the directories and I want to check when the queue is empty and I have k sleeping threads then for the next directory I want to take the thread that slept first

Comment: A "sleeping thread" is a thread that is _waiting for something._ What are the threads awaiting? In general, there are two ways in which thread A can "wake up" thread B; Either it can cause the event that B was awaiting (e.g., by "releasing" a semaphore, or by putting an object into a blocking queue), or in _some_ programming systems, it can "interrupt" B, (i.e., it can cause the function that B called to await the event to fail with an error code or an exception that means, "you were interrupted.")

Comment: Also, what is the relationship between the "k sleeping threads" and anything else (the queue, the directories, etc.) that you mentioned in your question? What do you expect a thread to do after you wake it?

Comment: Why does it matter which thread you use to process a given piece of work?  Thread pools are not usually concerned with that.

Comment: stackoverflow is not here to do your design/coding for you.  Please post what you have tried, so we can help you,

Answer (score 0):

You could create a thread queue out of something like this:

```
static pthread_mutex_t  TQLock;
typedef struct tqnode TQNode;
struct tqnode {
    pthread_cond_t wait;
    TQNode *next;
    /* other stuff. */
};
static TQNode *list;

void *NewThread(void *arg) {
    TQNode *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if (!p) abort();
    pthread_cond_init(&p->wait, 0);
    while (DoSomething(arg)) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&TQLock);
        /* append p on list */
        pthread_cond_wait(&p->wait, &TQLock);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&TQLock);
    }
    pthread_cond_destroy(&p->wait);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}

int Dispatch(void) {
    TQNode *p;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&TQLock);
    if ((p = list)) != 0) {
        list = p->next;
        pthread_cond_signal(&p->wait);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&TQLock);
}
```

Which would FIFO them through the list, but the instant that TQLock is released by Thread, it is possible that another thread could be awoken and beat it to the next instruction.